# Accessing timestamp part in data

Tags: python

My data format is:

```
2019-03-07T11:50:03.161033+01:00
```

My script:

```
import datetime
print datetime.datetime.strptime('2019-03-07T11:50:03.161033+01:00', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%Z')
```

I get the error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    print datetime.datetime.strptime('2019-03-07T11:50:03.161033+01:00', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%Z')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 332, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '2019-03-07T11:50:03.161033+01:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%Z'
```

How can I access the +01:00 timestamp part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in your original data format.

```
2019-03-07T11:50:03.161033+01:00
```

The timezone part, `+01:00` should actually be `+0100`, note the lack of the fullcolon.

If you were to change your original date format to a correct date format, `datetime.datetime.strptime` will work.

```
s = 2019-03-07T11:50:03.161033+0100
datetime.datetime.strptime(s,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')
[out] datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 7, 11, 50, 3, 161033, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(0, 3600)))
```

You could convert your date format as follows:

```
s = r'2019-03-07T11:50:03.161033+01:00'
lastSemiColor = s.rfind(':') # returns index
s = s[:ii] + s[ii+1:]
print(s) # returns '2019-03-07T11:50:03.161033+0100'
```

This can be found in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

```
%z  UTC offset in the form ±HHMM[SS[.ffffff]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import datetime

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = "2019-03-07T11:50:03.161033+01:00"
    b = datetime.datetime.strptime(a, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z").strftime("%z")

    print(b)
```

**Output**:

> +0100

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
   print('TimeStamp is : %d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d' % (
        timeObj.tm_mday, timeObj.tm_mon, timeObj.tm_year, timeObj.tm_hour, timeObj.tm_min, timeObj.tm_sec))
```

Comment: Where is the timeObj import?

Comment: That you can do where you import the other directives 
i just added the syntax. :)